# async-aware mock/override environment variables?

Tags: python, async-await, mocking

Is there an async-aware way to mock environment variables?

What I want is a context manager that lets me mock the code inside the `with` block, so that when that code is executing the mock is applied, but it's not applied when other code is executing.

Something like this, but passing:

```
import pytest
import os
import asyncio
import mock


async def aaa():
    with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"FAVORITE_LETTER": "A"}, clear=True):
        for _ in range(50):
            assert os.environ["FAVORITE_LETTER"] == "A"
            await asyncio.sleep(0)


async def bbb():
    with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"FAVORITE_LETTER": "B"}, clear=True):
        for _ in range(50):
            assert os.environ["FAVORITE_LETTER"] == "B"
            await asyncio.sleep(0)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_mock_env():
    await asyncio.gather(aaa(), bbb())
```

This currently fails with:

```
    async def aaa():
        with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"FAVORITE_LETTER": "A"}, clear=True):
            for _ in range(50):
>               assert os.environ["FAVORITE_LETTER"] == "A"
E               AssertionError: assert 'B' == 'A'
E                 - A
E                 + B

test_mock_env.py:9: AssertionError
```

=======

Edit:

The accepted answer addresses the question as I asked it, but doesn't solve my problem because I simplified too much when I made the example. My real problem wouldn't make a good example to paste here, but this is closer to my real situation:

```
from my_library import some_component_i_control
from someone_elses_library import not_my_code

async def wrap_not_my_code():
    with patch.dict(os.environ, {"ENV_VARS_NEEDED_FOR_COMPONENT_I_DONT_CONTROL": "A"}, clear=True):
        await not_my_code()  # this runs forever but does not block the event loop


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_mock_env():
    task_for_not_my_code = asyncio.create_task(wrap_not_my_code())
    task_for_my_component = asyncio.create_task(some_component_i_control())
    await asyncio.wait([task_for_my_component, task_for_not_my_code], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED) 
    # ...
    # Make some assertions about the results
```

I'm trying to test the interaction between a library I control, and one I don't, with the component I don't control seeing a modified version of the environment.

In fact it's even worse: I need multiple instances of the task for the component I don't control, all seeing different environments, and all running concurrently with my own code. Is that possible?

Comment: your tests are running concurrently, and this is causing a data race issue as you can see, why not just run them sequentially

Comment: My actual use case requires concurrency - the example here isn't anything real, so doesn't need concurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need something to allow exclusive access to state, in this case an `asyncio.Lock` object would work. This requires you to modify the original code to the following.

```
import pytest
import os
import asyncio
from unittest.mock import patch


async def aaa(lock):
    for _ in range(50):
        async with lock:
            with patch.dict(os.environ, {"FAVORITE_LETTER": "A"}, clear=True):
                assert os.environ["FAVORITE_LETTER"] == "A"
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


async def bbb(lock):
    for _ in range(50):
        async with lock:
            with patch.dict(os.environ, {"FAVORITE_LETTER": "B"}, clear=True):
                assert os.environ["FAVORITE_LETTER"] == "B"
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_mock_env():
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    await asyncio.gather(aaa(lock), bbb(lock))
```

Comment: This removes the concurrency, right? If I wanted that I wouldn't be doing any of this async at all, as you suggested in your comment.

Comment: this doesn’t remove concurrency at all, both functions run concurrently it just creates exclusive access to modifying the environment variable

Comment: For my use case I do need each coroutines env var to stay set, though -- setting/unsetting over and over in the loop won't work. I apologize for making an example that didn't capture that aspect of my situation.

Comment: can you provide an example in that case and I can modify my answer

Comment: thanks! I've edited the question to try to be clearer about my problem.